# Linq TakeWhile in loop, giving only first result

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using a takewhile statement in a loop and its only giving results on the first iteration of the loop. All the subsequent iterations are not producing results, even though I would expect them to.

For example the code below. The first iterations will give string a="blah1blah2blah3". On the second iteration I would expect a="blah2blah3", but the takewhile is giving nothing a="", its getting no elements.

In the real world scenario this is a big loop of logic, so I can't afford to do the takewhile outside of the loop. I've tried to use a combination of count() and take(), but count() gives all the elements that qualify, not the count of items that qualify until the condition is false.

Any help would be useful, thanks.

Code:

```
public void blah()
{
    List<testclass> someStrings = new List<testclass>() 
    { new testclass() { name = "blah1", testNum = 1 },
      new testclass() { name = "blah2", testNum = 2 },
      new testclass() { name = "blah3", testNum = 3 },
      new testclass() { name = "none4", testNum = 4 },
      new testclass() { name = "blah5", testNum = 5 },
      new testclass() { name = "blah6", testNum = 6 },
      new testclass() { name = "none7", testNum = 7 } 
    };

    foreach (testclass tc in someStrings)
    {
       string a = string.Join("", someStrings.TakeWhile(i => i.name.Contains("blah") 
                           && i.testNum >= tc.testNum).Select(g => g.name.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, because it starts from the start and not from your current element. You want to `skipWhile` you haven't reached the element and only then `takeWhile`, but measure performance this is the sort of thing that might be slow on large sets and a simple for loop can also solve it.

Comment: In the example you've shown `a` is unused, and can be optimized out entirely at some point before the code runs.  You need to actually use your result (by, say, writing it to the console or a text file) for the results to mean anything.

Comment: Is using `Aggregate` an option?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Why would that help?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Your solution is quite a bit poorer than the OPs, with the exception of the fact that the OP has one typo to fix (that you don't even mention in your answer).

Comment: You can use `string.Concat` instead of `string.Join`.

Comment: If `.name` is a compile-time `string` there is no point in `.name.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve from this but the problem with your code is, when you loop executes for second time i.e. for `testNum` as `2` your query looks like this:-

```
string a = someStrings.Where(i => i.name.Contains("blah")
                                    && i.testNum >= 2).Select(g => g.name.ToString());
```

So, Obviously the first condition itself will fail i.e. `i.testNum >= 2` for first element which contains `1` and you will get nothing or String.Empty as output.

As far as what I have understood, you can achieve what you want by adding `SkipWhile` before as suggested by @CodeDennis to skip previous records like this:-

```
string a = string.Join("", someStrings.SkipWhile(i => i.testNum < tc.testNum)
            .TakeWhile(i => i.name.Contains("blah") && i.testNum >= tc.testNum)
            .Select(g => g.name.ToString()));
```

Comment: Ah ok I see what's happening then. As for the resolution I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think that `Where` will give the correct results, but +1 for identifying why no results are returned in the 2nd iteration of the loop. A combination of `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` should do it.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Now I have a better understsanding of takewhile and its limitations, it only evaluates till the first false and then never re-evaluates. Using skipwhile is the trick. Thanks again.